# Labeling unlabeled dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I am having an `unlabeled` image data set. I need to get labels for them with predictions. I am doing rotation on the unlabeled dataset. `Degree of rotation` will be the predicted label. I have a code for that. But the dataset is not getting the label as i expect.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code.

```
class SesemiTransform:
    """
    Torchvision-style transform to apply SESEMI augmentation to image.
    """

    classes = ('0', '90', '180', '270', 'hflip', 'vflip')

    def __call__(self, x):
        tf_type = random.randint(0, len(self.classes) - 1)
        if tf_type == 0:
            x = x
        elif tf_type == 1:
            x = transforms.functional.rotate(x, 90)
        elif tf_type == 2:
            x = transforms.functional.rotate(x, 180)
        elif tf_type == 3:
            x = transforms.functional.rotate(x, 270)
        elif tf_type == 4:
            x = transforms.functional.hflip(x)
        elif tf_type == 5:
            x = transforms.functional.rotate(x, 180)
            x = transforms.functional.hflip(x)
        return x, tf_type 

  class UnlabeledDataset(Dataset):
        """
        Unlabeled training Dataset class.
        """
    
        def __init__(self, data: np.ndarray,
                transform: Optional[transforms.Compose] = None):
            self.data = data
            self.transform = transform
            self.sesemi_transform = SesemiTransform()
    
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.data)
    
        def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> np.ndarray:
            data = self.data[idx]
            if self.transform is not None:
                data = self.transform(data)
            data, label = self.sesemi_transform(data)
            return data, label
```

And this is how i set my unlabeled data

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_img,transform=transform)

labeled_trainset, unlabeled_trainset = torch.utils.data.random_split(trainset, [1000, 2300])

unsupervised_trainset = UnlabeledDataset(unlabeled_trainset)
```

I am a beginner, I dont know where it went wrong.
I was trying to print the image with label using imshow, i got this error. I gave 4 as n_show_images

This is the code

```
unsup_classes = unsupervised_trainset.sesemi_transform.classes
dataiter = iter(unlabeled_trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images[:n_show_images]))
print(' '.join(f'{unsup_classes[labels[j]]:5s}' for j in range(n_show_images)))
```

And i'm getting this error

```
<ipython-input-96-d3815a2df911> in <genexpr>(.0)
      3 images, labels = dataiter.next()
      4 imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images[:n_show_images]))
----> 5 print(' '.join(f'{unsup_classes[labels[j]]:5s}' for j in range(n_show_images)))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

TIA

Comment: Post the trace of the error

Comment: @Luke I have added it in the question now

Comment: Looks like `len(labels)` must be less than `n_show_images` in that `print` line, but it doesn't look like you've shown the actual code you are running that produces the error so it's hard to see where it's gone wrong.  Can you work backwards and make a minimal code sequence somebody else could run that would produce the error?

Comment: @TMBailey I have added the actual code now, can you able to identify the error?

Comment: Probably your next step is to put some more `print` lines in just before the `print` that produces an error.  `print(n_show_images)`, `print(labels)`, `print(len(labels))`, that sort of thing.

Comment: @TMBailey Thank you, I tried ```print(labels)```. I gave random values (0,1,..) . Sometimes it is giving the label, sometimes it is giving **IndexError: tuple index out of range** error. For same value also it is sometimes giving the label and sometimes giving error. So i'm somehow confused.